# mysqlite, inserting data and special character cases in perl

Tags: mysql, perl

I am  inserting data from perl in my sqlite database.

here is my coding:

how do i make this case work if my values have special characters like quotes?

```
sub ADDROWDATATODATABASE
{
    my $dbh1 = $_[0];
    my $table = $_[1];
    my @DATA = @{$_[2]};
    my $string = ();
    foreach (@DATA) { $string .= "'$_',"; } $string =~ s/,$//; 

    $dbh1->do(qq|insert into $table values(NULL,$string);|); 

    my $date = `date`;
    print "[MYSQLITE_ADDROW.pl] $date : ADDING DATA INTO DATABASE <p>";
}
```

Comment: this is sqlite, does it make a difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [placeholders and bind values](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values). This will keep your program safer from SQL injection, too.

```
my $statement = $dbh->prepare("insert into $table VALUES(NULL, ?,?,?,?)");
$statement->execute(@DATA);
```

---

Assuming that the number of elements in `@DATA` is only known at runtime (and that it is the correct number of elements for `$table`), you can use

```
my $statement = $dbh->prepare("insert into $table VALUES(NULL" . ",?"x@DATA . ")";
$statement->execute(@DATA);
```

to make sure that the statement has the right number of placeholders.

Answer (score -1):

You need to call a function to "escape" the values.  How you do that depends on what database you're actually using — MySQL and SQLite are different products.

Also, you should explicitly name the columns in the INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO Table (Col1, Col2) VALUES (Val1, Val2)
```